# Duplicate arrays pushed utilizing Fisher-Yates shuffle?

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to shuffle the elements of an array utilizing the Fisher-Yates algorithm. I then want to take this "shuffled" array and push it into another array. My goal is to create an array containing a specific amount of "shuffled" arrays.

For example:

```
var myInput = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and I would like my output to be something along the lines of:

```
myOutput = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 4], [2, 5, 1, 3, 4], [5, 3, 1, 4, 2]];
```

So the problem occurs AFTER I run my function. I provide an array and it outputs the same array with the elements "shuffled" as it should. I am running this function in a loop, let's just say for five (5) iterations, and with each iteration, the "shuffled" array is pushed to my output array. However, my final output array ends up with five (5) of the same "shuffled" arrays rather than five different ones. For some reason, it seems to be filled with the "shuffled" array from the LAST iteration of my loop.

Here is my code:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    };
    return array;
};


var myInput = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var myOutput = [];

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    var shuffledArr = shuffle(myInput);
    console.log(shuffledArr);
    myOutput.push(shuffledArr);
}

console.log(myOutput);
```

Like I said, myOutput ends up as a five (5) element array and each element is the array pushed from the FINAL iteration of my loop. In the loop, when the shuffledArr variable is logged to the console, it is definitely different then what seems to getting pushed to my output array.

Any ideas? I am super confused about this. I am assuming that something within the fisher-yates algorithm is causing the issue.

Comment: `shuffle` mutates the array, instead of creating a new one. You need to make a copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shuffling the same array reference each time and filling the larger array with 5 references to the same `myInput` array.

Changes to any one reference will affect all since they all point to the same physical array

Make a copy each iteration using `slice()` so you actually have a new array each time

```js
var myInput = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var myOutput = [];

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    var shuffledArr = shuffle(myInput.slice());   
    myOutput.push(shuffledArr);
}

console.log(myOutput);

function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    };
    return array;
};
```

---

Simplified example:

```
var a = [1,2];
b = a; // not a copy of the [1,2] array ... is reference to it
b[0] = 99;
console.log(a) // [99,2] ...same as `b`
```

Comment: My man! I thought that was sort of the case, but didn't think about using slice(). I tried adding a new array variable within the function and returning that new array however it ended up doing the same thing. Why would that be?

Comment: somewhat explained in my simplified example at end of my answer....what you think is a "new array" isn't...it's still a reference to the same array

Comment: Ahhh makes sense. Thanks!